# Я решл задачку с ACMP на питоне вот сама задача https://acmp.ru/index.asp?main=task&id_task=38

Tags: python

```
a=int(input())
d=input().split()
d1=d
i1=0
i2=0
Flag=1
#Flag=-1 это ход второго игрока
for i in range(len(d1)):
    if Flag==1:
        i1=i1+max(int(d1[0]),int(d1[len(d1)-1]))
        if int(d1[0])>int(d1[0]):
            d1.pop(d1[0])
        else:
            d1.pop([0])
    if Flag==-1:
        i2=i2+max(int(d1[0]),int(d1[len(d1)-1]))
        if int(d1[0])>int(d1[0]):
            d1.pop([0])
        else:
            d1.pop([0])
    Flag=Flag*-1
print(i1,',',i2)
if i1>i2:
    print(1)
if i1<i2:
    print(2)
if i1==i2:
    print(0)
```

Она не проходит скажите в чём проблема и если можно скиньте готовый код

Comment: Отлично. А в чем вопрос?

Comment: просто не проходит скажите в чём проблема

Comment: вы сначала опишите какой именно алгоритм вы использовали для определения победителя

Comment: я голосую за закрытие этого вопроса, потому что адресовать его следует автору проверяющей системы

Answer (score 0, accepted):

если бы вы сделали так:

```
d = list(map(int, input().split()))
```

вам не пришлось бы по всему коду потом писать `int(d1)` и т.п. нарываясь на возможную ошибку если забудете преобразовать данные

**ошибки:**

```
d1.pop([0])
```

вот это у вас что такое?

```
arr = [1, 2, 3, 4]

arr.pop([0])

print(arr)
```

> TypeError: 'list' object cannot be interpreted as an integer

Comment: спасибо а попом я удалял лишние элементы списка